# Need to execute a separate code for preventing screenshots and blur the app when it is in Recent app list

Tags: android, screenshot, android-security

I used below code to preventing the screenshots from my app.

```
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                     LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

But this did two action,

1) Prevented the screenshots

2) Blur the app when it is in recently used list

I want both actions to be done in separate code.

Is this possible?